# Программа не ожидает ввода с клавиатуры

Tags: java

Угадай букву

В первый раз программа ожидает пока я введу символ, а во второй раз с переменной res - нет. Вместо того, что бы ожидать ввода с клавиатуры программа сразу входит в цикл. В чем проблема?

```
public class Alphavite {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Загадайте букву");
    char ch = (char) reader.read();

    System.out.println("Угадайте букву");
    char res = (char) reader.read();

    while ((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || (ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z'))
    {
        if (res == ch)
        {
            System.out.println("Вы угадали! Загаданная буква - " + ch);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Не угадали. Попробуйте снова");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Сделайте вывод введенного после кадого ввода, сразу станет понятно куда копать.

Comment: Кстати, если ввести сразу 2 символа,  то все будет работать

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Alphavite {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Загадайте букву");
    char ch = (char) reader.read();
    reader.readLine();// ?!
    System.out.println("Угадайте букву");
    char res = (char) reader.read();

    while ((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || (ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z')) {
        if (res == ch) {
            System.out.println("Вы угадали! Загаданная буква - " + ch);
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Не угадали. Попробуйте снова");
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Ну или так:

```
public class Alphavite {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Загадайте букву");
    char ch = reader.readLine().charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Угадайте букву");
    char res = reader.readLine().charAt(0);

    while ((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || (ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z')) {
        if (res == ch) {
            System.out.println("Вы угадали! Загаданная буква - " + ch);
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Не угадали. Попробуйте снова");
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Только я не совсем понимаю зачем тут цикл.

Comment: Тут нужно пояснить, что в консольных java-приложениях нет возможности считывать отдельные нажатия клавиш клавиатуры. Ввод всегда завершается нажатием ENTER. См. также [(1)](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1758144), [(2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it)

Comment: Да, спасибо за дополнение

Comment: "Тут нужно пояснить, что в консольных java-приложениях нет возможности считывать отдельные нажатия клавиш клавиатуры. Ввод всегда завершается нажатием ENTER." Или напишите свой Sensor, используя while и Thread.sleep и делайте определенные действия на определенный символ ХА!

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, в данном случае достаточно было просто использовать другой метод. Зачем изобретать велосипед? ХА!

Comment: "Зачем изобретать велосипе" 1.Вело который предоставляет java работает только на Enter, + тащит за сабой кучу не нужного в оперативке. 2.возможность без перевода в String(ХА!), 3.Вы можете делать что угодно и как угодно на любой символ(ХА!). А так это совет что ничего невозможного нет(а не к теме:)) Ха! (как люблю этот ХА!:))

Comment: И "    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));" это странно. Выходит дубляж (InputStreamReader ничего против не имею, но BufferedReader).

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, Во-первых где вы увидели дубляж? Конструктор  BufferedReader принимает Reader, а не InputStream. XА!

Comment: "XА!" это вы:) "да дубляж, BufferedReader по моему это буферизированный поток? А значит он читает че-то и переносит в свой внутренний byte[] вопрос зачем? System.in помоему он и так в буфере сидит:) Источник: исходники Java:) ХА! (много ХА не бывает:))

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, а во-вторых о какой куче ненужного в оперативке вы говорите?О уже загруженной стандартной библиотке, или о вашем Sensor? В том и особенность консольного ввода, чтобы с Enter комманды вводить

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, и как вы новую строку считаете с InputStreamReader? ХА!

Comment: Ах да, это же "велосипед" разработчиков Java. Конечно проще написать какой-то левый Sensor, который будет по одному символу обрабатывать строки

Comment: "InputStreamReader" я не буду использовать Reader а возьму обычный InputStream, и буду пользоватся цикл + read до тех пор пока не встречу 10 байт(/n) и когда встречу, буум, строка моя. И так на любой символ(и так реализуется Sensors, + там sleep ведь ввод не бывает быстрым).

Comment: А так хорошая беседа:) Мож не будем челу мусорить в тему?

Comment: Почему не бывает быстрым, а если я скопирую какой-то текст в консоль. А вдруг у меня строка очень длинная, считывание по одному символу не самый оптимальный вариант. Да и я до сих пор не понимаю чем стандартный способ хуже? Зачем на определенные символы делать какие-то действия, если нам просто нужно прочитать строку??

Comment: "А так хорошая беседа:) Мож не будем челу мусорить в тему?" - единственное, в чем я  с вами согласен